# Building tuples from nested lists

Tags: python, list

Hi please how can I append the tuples in a nested list to list of dictionaries to form a new list of tuples as follow:

```
nde = [{'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9},
           {'length': 0.48, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9},
           {'length': 0.88, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9}]

dge = [[(1001, 7005),(3275, 8925)], [(1598,6009),(1001,14007)]]
```

How can I append them to have the outcome formatted thus:

```
rslt = [(1001, 7005, {'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9}... ]
```

I tried this:

```
[(k1[0], k1[1], k2) for k1, k2 in zip(dge, nde)]
```

but it doesnt give the desired result. Thanks

Comment: You have three dictionaries in `nde` but two lists/four tuples in `dge`.  That seems strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flatten the list of lists first and then use it with `zip`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [(k1[0], k1[1], k2) for k1, k2 in zip(chain.from_iterable(dge), nde)]
[(1001, 7005, {'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.35, 'type': '99', 'modes': 'cw'}),
 (3275, 8925, {'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.48, 'type': '99', 'modes': 'cw'}),
 (1598, 6009, {'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.88, 'type': '99', 'modes': 'cw'})]
```

Docs: [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

Answer (score 3):

You have nested list, so you should flatten them before ziping:

```
import itertools
[(k1[0], k1[1], k2) for k1, k2 in zip(itertools.chain(*dge), nde)]
```